# "this" keyword: Working mechanism in Java

Tags: java, this

After learning Java for sometime, its the first time the use of `this` keyword has confused me so much.

Here is how I got confused. I wrote the following code:

```
class BasicInheritanceTest3Base{
    private int x = 0;
    public int y;

    public void a() {
        x++;
        this.x++;
        System.out.println("BasicInheritanceTest3Base.a()");
        b();
        this.b();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public void b(){
        System.out.println("BasicInheritanceTest3Base.b()");
    }
}

public class BasicInheritanceTest3 extends BasicInheritanceTest3Base {
    private int x = 3;
    public int y = 2;

    public void b() {
        System.out.println("BasicInheritanceTest3.b()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BasicInheritanceTest3 bit2 = new BasicInheritanceTest3();
        bit2.a();
    }
}
```

I got the following output:

```
BasicInheritanceTest3Base.a()
BasicInheritanceTest3.b()
BasicInheritanceTest3.b()
2
0
```

Now the first question here is: Why `x` and `this.x` point to the `x` of base class and not the Child class? And if `this.x` points to the `x` of the base class, why `this.b()` calls the `b()` of child class? Is the behavior of this different for fields and methods?

However, the primary concern is regarding the `this` keyword's mechanism.
I mean you know, `this` points (refers) to the current object. If you think about, its not a magical behavior. There is got to be `this` field somewhere. For example, the `.class` literal for a class is invisible but is present in the emitted bytecode. Similarly, this reference should be present in the bytecode.

Alright, assuming above is true, `this` should be a `public final` (a blank final) which gets instantiated every time the object is constructed and its fields are instantiated. This implies that it is an instance variable not a static variable.

Now, if this gets instantiated to the current object's reference (which is a specific object only), how come above use of `this` is different for fields and methods? So all in all, what is the mechanism behind `this`? Does the mechanism also holds for the `super` keyword?

**EDIT:** Everyone reading the question and then the comments, I want to ask about, Where is `this` field declared by the compiler and what are its qualifiers. How does the resulting behavior happens behind the scenes?

Comment: Remember this simple rule: "fields are not polymorphic" (polymorphism in Java works only for methods which are not static, private or final). Since fields are not polymorphic their binding happens at compilation time, and at compilation time compiler doesn't know anything about derived classes so it binds `x` with closest available `x` it can find.

Comment: @Pshemo: I am all for it. It's the internals I am wondering about.

Comment: this keyword can be used for (It cannot be used with static methods):

To get reference of an object through which that method is called within it(instance method).
To avoid field shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.
To invoke constructor of same class.
In case of method overridden, this is used to invoke method of current class.
To make reference to an inner class. e.g ClassName.this

Comment: @Pshemo: Yeah, the binding thing is true indeed for fields and methods as I have come to read it too. It's the mechanism that mainly confuses me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's the mechanism that mainly confuses me" - it's as simple as "fields are not polymorphic".

Comment: @JonSkeet: I mean to ask that, Where is this field present exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet : How does this behavior happen behind the scenes? Where and how is the **this** field stored?

Comment: "*I want to ask about, where is this field declared by the compiler and what are its qualifiers*" you shouldn't think of `this` as a field. It is ***keyword*** which functionality depending on situation. For instance we can use `this(foo)` in constructor to invoke constructor accepting `foo` parameter. Generally purpose of `this` is to return current instance, but `this.x` represents accessing `x` variable where what `x` refers to will be determined at compilation time, while `this.method()` means "check what is actual class of *this* instance and look for `method`s code there and invoke it".

Comment: Why are you talking about `this` as a field at all? The aspect about fields and methods behaving differently isn't really related to the use of the `this` keyword... You'll see the same effect without it.

Comment: @Pshemo: I guess you are right. But I have come to observe and experience that, the more the abstraction level of something, the more chances of confusion are there. To avoid it, you have to dig every single detail to the bottom to be satisfied or you can rote learn the rules to some extent to remain satisfied. I personally keep falling down due to missing details. Most of the books "miss" out them for sake of simplicity. But Thank You.

Comment: @pulp_fiction So you want to explore foundation in order to be able to build more solid knowledge. Good approach. I am person with not very good memory and because of this I prefer to spend some time to actually understand how things work rather than memorizing it (since we don't need to memorize rules when we understand them). But unfortunately sometimes it is not worth the effort. To understand how Java work internally you would need to learn language in which it was written and see its code. But you can also try reading its specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html

Comment: @Pshemo : I am motivated enough now. I guess I am gonna read the spec. Funny thing, this falling out has been happening out to me in almost everything: C, C++, C#, Physics, Maths, Chemistry, and everything else. I have wasted many hours on "insignificant" things. Thank You for the link.

Comment: I want to reemphasize Jon's earlier comment: the behavior you've observed has **absolutely nothing** to do with `this`. So you've really asked two separate and completely unrelated questions here, which prompt for separate and lengthy answers. (Technically, if we are counting, you've asked 7 questions.) If the answers you've received do not fully address your pondering, you should consider revising your question so it's not so broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers and comments have explained how fields are not polymorphic and how field access expressions are resolved based on the compile time type of the instance reference. Below, I explain how the byte code handles the `this` reference.

In the chapter about *Receiving Arguments*, the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.6) states

> If n arguments are passed to an instance method, they are received, by
>   convention, in the local variables numbered 1 through n of the frame
>   created for the new method invocation. The arguments are received in
>   the order they were passed. For example:
>
> ```
> int addTwo(int i, int j) {
>     return i + j;
> }
> ```
>
> compiles to:
>
> ```
> Method int addTwo(int,int)
> 0   iload_1        // Push value of local variable 1 (i)
> 1   iload_2        // Push value of local variable 2 (j)
> 2   iadd           // Add; leave int result on operand stack
> 3   ireturn        // Return int result
> ```
>
> **By convention, an instance method is passed a reference to its
>   instance in local variable 0. In the Java programming language the
>   instance is accessible via the `this` keyword.**
>
> Class (static) methods do not have an instance, so for them this use
>   of local variable 0 is unnecessary. A class method starts using local
>   variables at index 0. If the addTwo method were a class method, its
>   arguments would be passed in a similar way to the first version:
>
> ```
> static int addTwoStatic(int i, int j) {
>     return i + j;
> }
> ```
>
> compiles to:
>
> ```
> Method int addTwoStatic(int,int)
> 0   iload_0
> 1   iload_1
> 2   iadd
> 3   ireturn
> ```
>
> The only difference is that the method arguments appear starting in
>   local variable 0 rather than 1.

In other words, you can either view `this` as not being declared anywhere or as being declared as the first parameter of every instance method. A local variable table entry is created for each instance method and populated on each invocation.

The chapter on [*Invoking methods*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7) states

> The normal method invocation for a instance method dispatches on the
>   run-time type of the object. (They are virtual, in C++ terms.) Such an
>   invocation is implemented using the `invokevirtual` instruction, which
>   takes as its argument an index to a run-time constant pool entry
>   giving the internal form of the binary name of the class type of the
>   object, the name of the method to invoke, and that method's descriptor
>   (§4.3.3). To invoke the `addTwo` method, defined earlier as an instance
>   method, we might write:
>
> ```
> int add12and13() {
>     return addTwo(12, 13);
> }
> ```
>
> This compiles to:
>
> ```
> Method int add12and13()
> 0   aload_0             // Push local variable 0 (this)
> 1   bipush 12           // Push int constant 12
> 3   bipush 13           // Push int constant 13
> 5   invokevirtual #4    // Method Example.addtwo(II)I
> 8   ireturn             // Return int on top of operand stack;
>                         // it is the int result of addTwo()
> ```
>
> **The invocation is set up by first pushing a reference to the current
>   instance, `this`, on to the operand stack.** The method invocation's
>   arguments, `int` values 12 and 13, are then pushed. When the frame for
>   the `addTwo` method is created, the arguments passed to the method
>   become the initial values of the new frame's local variables. **That is,
>   the reference for `this` and the two arguments, pushed onto the operand
>   stack by the invoker, will become the initial values of local
>   variables 0, 1, and 2 of the invoked method.**

Comment: Finally, the kind of answer I have been looking for, investigating the low level details. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

*Why x and this.x point to the x of base class and not the Child class?*

Because fields in Java are not polymorphic. Fields binding is resolved at compilation time. If you wanted to use incrementing as polymorphism you could do it with a method. To perform correctly you would need to define it in parent and child.

```
public void increment(){
    x++; //this.x++; would do the same;
}
```

*And if this.x points to the x of the base class, why this.b() calls the b() of child class?*

Because methods on the other hand are polymorphic, which means their binding is resolved at run-time and that's why this.b() calls method from the child class, in your case this is instance of BasicInheritanceTest3 and corresponding method is called.

*Is the behavior of this different for fields and methods?*

As you see it is.

Super is a reference to base class, so you can access it when for example needing to call overridden methods or/and hidden fields.

EDIT Reply:
this is a reference which means it is only address of the object along with all it's data in memory of JVM, how JVM handles this keyword is not really known or important, it is probably declared at instantiation. But all you need to know in the end is that this is reference to instance of Object himself.

Comment: Read the EDIT and the "later part" of question. What you are saying is I already know.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why x and this.x point to the x of base class and not the Child class?**

we can see this example:

```
class TestBase {
    private int x;
    public void a() {
        this.x++;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
public class Test extends TestBase{
    private int x;
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

and generated bytecode:

```
public class Test extends TestBase{
public Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method TestBase."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public int getX();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #2; //Field x:I
   4:   ireturn

public void a();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #3; //Method TestBase.a:()V
   4:   return

}
```

In there the `Test` `extends` `TestBase` and the method `a` is compiled into the `Test` class, it will call it's father `1:   invokespecial   #3; //Method TestBase.a:()V`.

the `Test`'s `getX` method will call `1:   getfield        #2; //Field x:I` from it's own `constant pool table`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

the `TestBase` class bytecode:

```
class TestBase extends java.lang.Object{
TestBase();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public void a();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   getfield        #2; //Field x:I
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   iadd
   7:   putfield        #2; //Field x:I
   10:  return

public int getX();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #2; //Field x:I
   4:   ireturn

}
```

the method `a()` also will get `x` from it's own constant pool by `getfield        #2; //Field x:I`.

so there is another thing: the Java's `getter` and `setter` is evil.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact , polymorphism property in JAVA programming language can only be applied for **methods** that have enough qualification to be polymorphic members. You are not supposed to think of **Fields** as members that have the mentioned property.Thus you won't get confused about such issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT answer]
I did a little bit of research and got the following info to answer your question further.
We can indeed verify that `this` is part of the bytecode by using a reverse engineering tool to convert the bytecode back into the java source.

> Why would we find the `this` in the bytecode?

Because since java is multi pass compiler and since bytecode can be expected to be run on any other platform and any other machine, all the information has got to be in bytecode, enough information to be able to reverse engineer the bytecode into the source code. Furhter, since the source code would have to be the same as the original source for the bytecode, everything including the exact names of the variables and fields would have to be "somehow" kept well organized with all the information in the bytecode.
Whereas C++ or pascal, unlike java, which use a single pass compiler, would mostly not keep exact names of fields and since such languages output a final "executable" file which has to be ready to be run, may care less to maintain the exact names(the instruction doesn't have to go thru another "pass") . If anybody reverse engineers an executable file (C++ or Pascal), the variable names would not be human readable. So in bytecode "this" may be represented as non-human readable format but the same could be reverse engineered back into "this". The same is not true for the single-pass compiler.

[Multi Pass Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler)

Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference. 
Also, class methods cannot use the `this` keyword as there is no instance for `this` to refer to.

> Now the first question here is: Why x and this.x point to the x of
>   base class and not the Child class?

It is because polymorphic behavior is not applicable for fields, so the results are from the base class.

> why this.b() calls the b() of child class? Is the behavior of this
>   different for fields and methods?

With this line:  BasicInheritanceTest3 bit2 = new BasicInheritanceTest3();
The only object in heap (in terms of base and child class) is the object of type `BasicInheritanceTest3`. So regardless of `this`, the call will apply to the child class method. `bit2` is referencing to its own hierarchy(of inheritance) in heap.

Now - how the compiler deals with it is same as how any other key/reserved words are dealt with by the jdk. **this** is not allowed in the context of **class methods**
Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference. Also, class methods cannot use the this keyword as there is no instance for this to refer to. Indeed an intriguing question hence gave the OP an up vote for the question.

More helpful info I read was along the lines of:
Identifiers and reserved keywords are tokens as are single characters like + and sequences of characters like !=.

I'd like to request community to keep this topic. I hadn't explored on how jdk (both compiler and the runtime) treat the keywords and reserved words.

[Java Api Docs: this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)