# 'this' keyword in stack or heap ?

Tags: java, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

Can anyone tell me the memory location of java keyword `this` ? is it in the *stack* or in the *heap*? eg:

```
Student st = new Student();
```

- `st` is a instance variable and it is stored in `stack`
- `this` is a reference variable that refers to the current object
  [image]

**Does that means `this` is just like `st`, because they both are reference variables, they both stored in *stack* and point to the same object `new Student()` in heap?**

And can anyone suggest some books for me about related contents above?

Thanks

Comment: `this` simply represents the current object, and so it is on the heap.

Comment: And don't confuse variables with their references. Just because st is on the stack, the Student object that it refers to is on the heap. Also check out [Stack and Heap memory in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java) from the [Software Engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks. so there is no actual memory allocation for `this`, right?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By the same token (pun intended), `this` is a variable on the stack, and it points to an object on the heap.

Comment: A much better duplicate link: [“this” keyword: Working mechanism in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472208/this-keyword-working-mechanism-in-java). So in any instance method, `this` is variable 0 pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @yshavit: exactly! good question here, although it has been asked before.

Comment: @yshavit that's exactly what I thought

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hey bro, so your first answer was not correct, `this` should be in the stack, am I right, and it point to the object created

Comment: It's never that clear. See what @yshavit states above

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry to bother you again mate, any books that you recommend me to look in terms of the working mechanism of Java?

Comment: Check out [Core Java Volumes 1 and 2 by Cay Horstmann](https://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html)

Comment: It's always that clear. It's always a parameter, so it's always on the stack. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @EJP: true. the thing that often confuses newbies is that while the parameter is always on the stack, the object that it refers to is on the heap.